# kubernetes pod performance hurt

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, throughput

I deploy my program, which simply sends data to client, at a gcloud VM and a kubernetes pod, but they display huge throughput difference.

For the gcloud VM, the throughput could be 20~25MBps.
But for the same program, deployed at a cluster pod, its throughput only has ~10MBps.
The pod has Guarenteed QoS, with requested and limits both 10CPU and 64GB mem.
I used `iperf` to test the b/w, both have >800MBps.

Is there some configuration I need to handle?

Comment: What network overlay do you use in GKE?

Comment: Did you enable a CPU limit? If so, try removing that.

Comment: how did you configure your vm? and are you running the same application also as a container on the vm? and if so with what container daemon?